# Prisma Json vs Json[]

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm new to Prisma. I have a question about using `Json` vs. `Json[]`:

For my use case, I could use `Json` and just make the value always have a key value like this:

```
{
    "list": [ ... ]
}
```

Or I could just use `Json[]`, which to me is better. But is `Json` more performant than `Json[]`?

Comment: `Json` would be sufficient in this case.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for the response. Which one is more performant though?

Comment: I don't think there's any performance difference b/w the two.